# How do you "resolve" a GKTurnBasedExchange?

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm using a GKTurnBasedExchange to send data one way. It's a notification to the other players as certain triggers happen. However, the other players may not even be in the game at that time. The turns have 48 hour timeouts, so in theory if player1 sends said exchange, player3 might not pick it up for a couple of days. That's fine, player 1 doesn't require or expect any response.

But, when player1 tries to save the match data, end the turn or quit the match, I get an error:

> Error Domain=GKErrorDomain Code=3 "The requested operation could not
>   be completed due to an error communicating with the server."
>   UserInfo=0x19317970 {GKServerStatusCode=5134,
>   NSUnderlyingError=0x16f15db0 "The operation couldn’t be completed.
>   status = 5134, Invalid operation for this session because the exchange
>   was not resolved. **All exchanges must be resolved before the current
>   player can complete this operation**.

OK, the bolded text seems pretty self-explanatory except for one little detail: I can't find any reference anywhere to what constitutes a "resolved" exchange. I don't expect a response back to this message. Even if I did, it could take days to receive it. The only option I can see is for the sender to cancel the exchange, which defeats the purpose of sending the exchange in the first place

So, how exactly does one finalize an exchange? What series of steps, besides canceling the exchange, will satisfy game center that the exchange has been "resolved?"
I'm just using:

```
    [theMatch sendExchangeToParticipants:exchangeParticipants
                                    data:exchangeData
                   localizableMessageKey:@"F1"
                               arguments:nil
                                 timeout:600
                       completionHandler:^(GKTurnBasedExchange *exchange, NSError *error)
                       {
                           if (error)
                           {
                               VLOG(LOWLOG, @"%@", [error description]);
                           }
                       }
    ];
```

Followed by:

```
[theMatch saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData:dataCopy completionHandler:^(NSError *error)
 {
     if (error)
     {
         VLOG(LOWLOG, @"%@", [error description])
     }
 }];
```

The saveCurrentTurnWithMatchData call returns the aforementioned error.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I figured this out. *Man oh  man* it's a slog making sense of Apple's documentation.

In the end I didn't make sense of it actually: this is the result of brute force trial and error.

So here's the deal: you can do a lot of things with exchanges, but to actually *resolve* them you have to call:

```
saveMergedMatch(matchData: Data, withResolvedExchanges: [GKTurnBasedExchange], completionHandler: ((Error?) -> Void))
```

*There are several catches though.*

- Only the match's `currentParticipant` (the player who's turn it is) can call `saveMergedMatch` successflly.
- It will only work for exchanges that are not in `.active` status.
- There are only two ways, as far as I can tell, to programmatically get an exchange out of `.active` status.
- The harder way: all recipients of the exchange have to act on the exchange--itself a murky process, can't help there. If all recipients do respond to it, Game Center itself will handle changing the status of the exchange, *I think*. Not sure though, because I don't do this. [The only help I can give here is that if you give an exchange a really short timeout when you send it, after the timeout passes Game Center will adjust the exchange's status automatically, and your recipients won't have to do anything.]
- The not-much-easier way: the sender *and only the sender* of the exchange can cancel it, by calling the exchange's method `cancel(withLocalizableMessageKey key: String, arguments: [String], completionHandler: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil)`. The saving grace of this way is that *it doesn't have to be the sender's turn* for them to cancel it. This is one of the few times that the current turn-taker doesn't matter. Unfortunately this also has a catch: the exchange can't be cancelled if anyone has already responded to it.

So the upshot is that there is no way for any single player to be guaranteed to be able to resolve an exchange, for two reasons:

1. The process that moves *active* exchanges into *completed* exchanges is only programmatically accessable for the purpose of cancelling the exchange, and only by the player that originated it, and only if no one has responded yet.
2. The actual process that turns *completed* exchanges into *resolved* exchanges can only be triggered by the player in the match's `currentParticipant` property.

Personally, I can work with this, now that I understand it *(I hope)* , but without doubt it is quite a pain.

Comment: Wow, great info! *that's* the kind of info I wish was in Apple's docs.

Comment: I know right? I'm banging my head against this for days and I'm glad if I can help anyone else skip all that trouble.

Answer (score 1):

Well, turns out exchanges can't be used. Yet another limitation in Game Kit. For anyone that comes across this thread, I found WWDC 2013 session 506 says:

1. All participants have to respond for game center to mark the exchange as "completed"
2. You have to call:

   ```
   [match saveMergedMatchData:dataCopy
        withResolvedExchanges:match.completedExchanges
            completionHandler:...];
   ```

So, you can't use exchanges for 1-way communications. There has to be a response (or wait for a timeout).

Comment: My problem is that the server returns an error when a recipient tries to reply to an exchange.

Comment: Sure you can use exchanges for one-way communication. When the exchange request is received, check the parameters you receive, and immediately reply to acknowledge receipt. If no receipt is received by the sender, then the message was not received.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I'll answer to the unasked question of: how to send 1-way communications With notifications.

I think the best API for that is setLocalizableMessageWithKey(key:arguments:) or sendReminderToParticipants(localizableMessageKey:arguments:completionHandler:) on your GKTurnBasedMatch instance.

Comment: There are limits to both of those, though. `setLocalizableMessageWithKey` can only be executed by the current owner of the match, and in my testing, the other players only receive an updated message when the owner actually ends the turn (not when the owner saves the match). I haven't retested that on IOS9, tho. SendReminder had more promise; however, it's got a time-limit throttle.

Comment: I think it works to set a 1-millisecond timeout on the exchange. That way the exchange gets automatically moved out of `.active` status, all on its own. And then in your `GKLocalPlayerListener` imlementation you can handle the actual contents of the exchange, with no need to reply.